# Read XML file and display value using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, file, xml-parsing

I want to read an XML file in PowerShell and display value of node `success="True"` in `<First-suite>`, but it's not working as expected. Below is my XML file.

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=""....?>
<First-results name="myassemble.dll" total="5" errors="0" failures="0">
  <database multiversion"2323" os-version="Win10" platform="32bit"/>
  <mssql-info current-current="en-A" current-aiculture="en-A"/>
  <First-suite type "myassembly" name="mydll" executed="true" result="Success" success="True" time="3.66">
    <MyTest>  </MyTest>
  </First-suite>
</First-results>
```

My sample code:

```bsh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'c:\MyFile.xml'
$xml_FirstResults = $xml.SelectNodes('First-results /First-suite')
foreach ($Test in $xml_FirstResults) {
    Write-Host($Test.success)
}
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid. Please make sure that sample data in your question is correct and reflects your actual data when posting a question.

Comment: With that said, The reason why your sample code doesn't work is the trailing space after `First-results`. Change `'First-results /First-suite'` to `'First-results/First-suite'` (better yet: `'/First-results/First-suite'`) and the code will do what you want.

Comment: Exception calling "SelectNodes" with 1 arguments:"'/First-results/First-suite' has an invalid token"

Comment: @Ansgar There is some problem with my tags. Anyhow its working now. Thanks for quick resolution

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a single XPath query.

```
$xml | Select-Xml -XPath "//First-suite[@success='True']/*"
```

Comment: `//First-suite[@success='True']/*`. That returns the entire node, though. For just the attribute you'd use `//First-suite/@success[.='True']`. Either way, when using `Select-Xml` you still need to expand the `Node` property of the result, and then the `#text` property of that result to get to the actual attribute value. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519859/1630171).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Probably I've misunderstood something.but the OP's question was about node value, not attribute value.

Comment: Hmm... or maybe I misunderstood something. Getting the node value makes more sense than getting an attribute value that you're already filtering by. Still, the need to expand the `Node` and then `#text` when using `Select-Xml` remains.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I believe that use of `Select-Xml` is better in matter of speed and/or readability than iterating through nodes with `foreach`.